# Who to know the latest commit review number looking at the svn local database or files?

Tags: svn

I need to know what was the latest revision number I commited to svn but **I don't have access to the server** right now. Is it possible to know the review number looking at the svn local database or files?

Comment: What 'review number' is?

Comment: I think he meant "revision number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a SQLite file located in the .svn directory which is named "wc.db".

In this SQLite database, there is a table named NODES.

This query served for my purpose. I am not sure it it would serve for any situation. After I got connection to the SVN server I was able to validate that the result of that query was the latest revision I had commited.

`SELECT MAX(revision) FROM NODES WHERE changed_author='yecarri'`

*Please take this answer with care. I am not an expert in the svn architecture,* I just wanted to share what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to interrogate the repository itself, there is no way to know what the latest committed revision in the repository is. You might have some data cached in your working copy about the latest revision *at the time you last updated* but that may be out of date seconds after `svn update` completes.

To see what your working copy knows, use `svn info PATH_TO_WORKING_COPY` and `svn log PATH_TO_WORKING_COPY`but these are not authoritative.